# Script to compare two tables in database, from user input

Tags: sql, database, vba

I am very new to VBA and SQL and am trying to learn. I have a MS Access project that requires a VBA script that prompts the user to input two table names and numerous field names and create a SQL query utilizing those the names.

The specific SQL query I'm trying to use is below.

```
SELECT 
   A.user_index, A.input1, B.input1, A.input2, B.input2, A.input3, B.input3, B.input4, 
   A.input4, A.input5, B.input5 
FROM 
   table1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
   table2 AS B ON A.user_index = B.user_index 
WHERE 
   (((A.input1) <> [B].[input1)) OR 
   (((A.input2) <> [B].[input2])) or
   (((A.input4) <> [B].[input4]));
```

The overall purpose of this is to have a script that will be able to list fields for comparison that is applicable with any database. I know this is probably a relatively easy solution. However, I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first instinct is to say "What have you tried so far?", but as you said, you don't know where to start.

It sounds like you need to first prompt the user for several field and table names, then build a query based on those values.  I recommend first outlining *exactly* what you want your script to do. Maybe something like:

1. Declare variables to hold the values.
2. Prompt the user for each of the values and store them in the variables.
   2a. After the user enters a value, make sure it is valid. If not, do something accordingly.
3. Declare a variable to hold your SQL query.
4. Construct the query.
5. Run the query.

This is obviously just an example.  Break down each step into "baby steps" as much as possible.

It's a good idea to ask yourself how unique these baby steps are to your particular situation (hint: *they almost certainly are not unique*).  If they aren't, then they have probably been solved tens of thousands of times already, so you have a very good chance of googling your questions.

If you still can't find an answer to how to do a particular step, feel free to ask here. Just remember to include your code even if it is broken :)